# Unable to disable TLSv1/TLSv1.1 in Apache 2.4.18

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache2

A client has requested that I disable TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 on a web server. The server is running Apache 2.4.8. and OpenSSL 1.0.2g.

I have added the directive to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf`:

`SSLProtocol TLSv1.2`

Restarting Apache2 and running test on SSL Labs (and two other tools) shows that TLSv1 and 1.1 are still enabled. I have tried a lot of variations of the SSLProtocol directive, based on Googling around:

`SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2`

`SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1`

`SSLProtocol +all -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1`

None of them work. I have also tried adding the directive to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. This also makes no difference.

I have no idea how to proceed. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the configuration line you change is the one taken into account? Did you try locally with `openssl s_client`? Or with https://testssl.sh/ or https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools/blob/master/analyze-ssl.pl ? Because `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2` just by itself should be enough, see https://serverfault.com/questions/848177/how-can-i-disable-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-apache  You can also see there that sslabs caches reports so the results you see may not be the live ones... better to check locally first.

Answer (score 0):

Edit vhost/site.conf

for me its works

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
######################################################
# support old Android phones
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1

# Force using custom cipher list
SSLHonorCipherOrder on

Define sslCiphers -ALL:!ADH:!aNULL:!EXP:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!3DES:!eNULL:!NULL:!RC4:!DES:!MD5:!LOW
Define sslCiphers ${sslCiphers}:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA
SSLCipherSuite ${sslCiphers}
```